# Аналог AJAX в PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Как обратится к другому файлу в `PHP`, чтобы только запустить скрипт, без обратной отправки результата?

Нужно без применения `include` или `require`.

Например в `JQuery`:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/files/ajax_lg.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {"check_user": checkPin},
            async: false
        });
```

А как это реализовать в `PHP`?

Comment: `shell_exec` ....... `curl` :D

Comment: С помощью file_get_contens получить скрипт в строку и затем eval :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Большое спасибо

Comment: Я подозреваю, что у вас проблема в чём-то другом. Но из описания задачи этого не понять. И вы в итоге будете прикручивать костыльный велосипед...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выкладываю результат, как сделал эту работу я через cURL

```
//cURL";
        $url = http://domen/?param=1;
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        $response_data = curl_exec($ch);
        //echo $response_data;
        curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример кода старый, но не суть.

В скрипте `/files/ajax_lg.php` запускайте другой скрипт, например, как в примере через `exec` не забывая в конце команде добавить `> /dev/null 2>&1 &` — это запустить скрипт в фоне и вызов `/files/ajax_lg.php` буквально сразу вернет «результат» и ничего ждать не нужно.

**На стороне клиента, в браузере**

```js
// Выполняете запрос без перезагрузки страницы
$.ajax({
    url: '/files/run_task.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {"check_user": checkPin},
    async: false
});
```

**Так, например, может выглядить ваш скрипт в файле `/files/run_task.php`**

Где `/files/run_task.php` какой-то скрипт, который выполняется продолжительное время и который вы запускаете в фоне.

```php
// /files/run_task.php

$script = APPLICATION_PATH . '/files/ajax_lg.php';

$command  = 'php ' . $script;
$command .= ' > /dev/null 2>&1 &';

exec($command, $output, $status);
```

Ну даже в таком случае будет правильно, если вызов `/files/ajax_lg.php` будет что-то возвращать. Потому что до вызова `exec()` могут быть ошибки...

---

Суть в том, и вы это поняли, чтобы веб-сервер «сразу» отправил обратно ответ на запрос (`/files/ajax_lg.php`), веб-серверу «приходится ждать» полностью выполнения скрипта (или пока не произойдет ошибка). Чтобы не дожиться выполнения какого-то скрипта — его можно запустить в фоне. Обрабатывать ошибки, если они возникают в таком скрипте — уже другая история...

Comment: Помоги еще малость разобраться.
Я отправляю с index.php запрос в ajax.lg.
Не могу понять, что такое $output, $status?

Comment: @vks слушаю...)

Comment: И $script = APPLICATION_PATH . '/files/ajax_lg.php?e=12345'; - подойдет?

Comment: @vKs Я пример своего кода указал. APPLICATION_PATH это у меня была объявлена константа ещё. Она вам не нужна, если конечно у вас он не такая же Оо `$script` — это путь к скрипту, который вы хотите выполнить. Какой указывать путь это вы только сейчас свою структуру знаете. Так... сейчас немного ответ изменю...

Comment: @vKs постарался пояснить. Не нужно копировать код 1 в 1: не в смысле нельзя — наоборот можно, а в смысле всегда старайтесь разобраться с самим принципом... Почитайте о команде [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php), ниже на странице в блоке Смотрите также — вы также можете увидеть альтернативные команды, может быть они лучше вам подходят... Тут уже сами ришайте.

Comment: @vKs то есть у вас должен быть запрос к одному скрипту (например, `/files/run_task.php`), а в этом скринпе должен в фоне запускаться другой скрипт (`/files/ajax_lg.php`). Но учтите скрипт `/files/ajax_lg.php` запускается в фоне. Вы же не ждете от него какого-нибудь значения после выполнения? Если ждете — нужно менять логику программы, что в моем примере.

Comment: Спасибо, но Ваш пример мне не подходит. Логику его я понял, но это очень много кода.
Подошел вариант с cURL

Comment: @vks ничего. Если несложно - опубликуйте решение.