# Обновление данных с mssql каждые 5 секунд

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server

Ребята , есть скрипт на подключение к базе данных и считывание собственно самих данных но вот проблема , в базе элементы новые записались ,а на странице надо обновлять только с помощью f5 + не все как надо выводится потому что в КЕШЕ остается инфа еще . Как это сделать обновление статичным?

```
 <?php

// раметры подключения
$serverName = "localhost, 1433"; 
$uid = "web_user";   
$pwd = "Gf45Rn27G";  
$databaseName = "plc_server"; 
$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid, "PWD"=>$pwd,"Database"=>$databaseName); 
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connectionInfo);

// переменнные для запроса
$page = 1;
$group = 1;
$enable = 1;

if ($conn){
    //echo "Подключение к серверу успешно!<br/>";

    // обработка запроса  
    $tsql = "SELECT SVG_NAME,PARAMETERS,TYPE_PARAMETERS FROM SVG_PARAMETERS  WHERE SVG_PAGE='$page' and SVG_GROUP='$group' and ENABLE='$enable' ";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql); 

    if( $stmt === false )  
        {  
            echo "Error in statement preparation/execution.\n";  
        }  

    if($stmt  === false)  
        {  
            echo "Error in retrieving row.\n";  
        } 

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)) {
  echo "SVG_NAME: ".$row[0]."--->>>".$row[1]."--->>>".$row[2]."</br>"; 


}
}else{
    echo "Нет подключения к серверу. <br/>";
}


sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);  
sqlsrv_close( $conn); 

?>
```

Comment: Можно по таймеру с 5секундным интервалом использовать ajax-запрос и подменять содержимое контейнера, где выводится информация из БД.

Comment: Пока что не представляю как это сделать ...(Можно наглядный пример ?

Comment: попробуйте в JS [setInterval](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval)

Comment: По моему через setInterval  информация в кеше все равно останется ,а надо чтоб с базы обновлялось и инфа в кеше не засиживалась ...

Comment: Есть примеры как такое сделать ?

Comment: Если речь о кеше браузера, то при обращении к скрипту передаывайте параметр случайное число (и/или время) тогда браузер не будет использовать кеш

Comment: @Karter делаеть срабатывание ajax по setInteval - пробуйте эксперементируйте, если что-то будет не работать крепите код будем смотреть :-) Не совсем понимаю о каком кэше идёт речь если данные приходят из БД и вы будете обновлять \ добавлять полученные данные

Comment: может что-то типа этого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701179/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-ajax-%D0%B2-php? Я увидел в тегах просто javascript, поэтому ajax посоветовал, это jQuery библиотека. Потом только уже увидел, что код целиком на php

Comment: Хорошо,сейчас попробую через сетинтервал сделать , если что не так отпишу.